# Is it still O(n) space if we don't perform the actual assignment?

Tags: swift, algorithm, sorting

Consider the **Valid Anagram** question where we return `true` if two strings are anagrams of each other:

`e.g. validAnagram("name", "mane")` returns `true`.

Assuming that we can only pass in the strings by value, a possible solution is to store the two sorted arrays into new variables, and then return whether those variables are equal:

```
    func validAnagram(_ s: String, _ t: String) -> Bool {
        guard s.count == t.count else { return false }
        
        let sortedS = s.sorted()
        let sortedT = t.sorted()
     
        return sortedS == sortedT
    }
```

In this case, the algorithm has a time complexity of `O(nlogn)`, and space complexity `O(2n) => O(n)`

My question is whether changing the function to the following makes the space complexity `O(1)`:

```
func validAnagram(_ s: String, _ t: String) -> Bool {
    guard s.count == t.count else { return false }
    return s.sorted() == t.sorted()
}
```

Is this true? Or is memory still allocated in the background to remember what `s.sorted()` and `t.sorted()` are, even though I am not explicitly initializing variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference. You still allocate memory for sorted arrays.

To avoid using additional space you need to sort data in-place if it's possible.